# Eclipse Neon 2, "No local history available for selected resource" for all files

Tags: eclipse, history

I have updated many files many times, but the history window is always blank, and if I do right click on the file then "compare with local history..." it always pops up and says "No local history available for selected resource"

When I go to Window ->Preferences > General > Workspace > Local History, I see "Limit history size" is ticked with 7 days, 50 entries per file and 1MB max file size.

However, if i edit and save a file with 10 lines in it, there is no history.

How do I get local history working?

This is a real killer because the groovy eclipse plugin keeps crashing, and then I can't save the file so each time it happens I lose all my changes.

I updated to neon 3, but same problem - no local history.

## Update

I didnt realise, its just groovy files for which no local history exists.  Unfortunately, this is 99% of my files (grails)

Comment: Which editor are you using? The editor has to specify that history should be kept when it does a save. Does history work using text plain xxx.txt file editor?

Comment: Good point. I am mainly editing groovy files. I just noticed that if I edit other files (e.g. txt or gradle), local history works! So its just that the groovy editor for eclipse which is "broken".

Answer (score 0):

The editor crash you mention and the inability to store local history are both symptoms of the same root problem.  The Groovy Editor is losing connection with the Document buffer (the source you see displayed in the editor view).  When this happens, a whole lot of capabilities stop working.

Please have a look at this issue: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/155

A fresh set of logs and some recreation steps are critical to solving the root cause.